# Return em each getJSON - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Gostaria de saber o seguinte como faço para dar return em uma função criada por mim, em uma situação abaixo. Pois sempre retorna undefined o objeto, mas quando dou um alerta ele retorna o objeto normal.

```
  function jjson(url){
            var result;
            $.getJSON( url, function(data) {
                alert(data)
                result = data;
            });

            return result;
        }
```

ATT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essa função vai sempre dar return *undefined* porque o AJAX é assíncrono.

Tens de usar uma *callback* para fazeres o que precisas quando a resposta do servidor chegar. 
Podes usar assim:

```
function jjson(url, callback){
        $.getJSON( url, callback);
 }
```

e depois chamas a função passando para a callback o que queres fazer:

```
jjson('google.com', function(result){
    alert(result);
});
```

Na prática isto pode ser simplificado se colocares o que queres fazer diretamente no getJSON...

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    gerarGrafico(data); //por exemplo
});
```

Pois assim esse código é corrido só quando os dados do servidor tiverem chegado.

Comment: Obrigado... ATT

Comment: Então é impossível utilizar os dados fora dele, colocar em uma variável ou dar um retorno pra ser utilizado?

Comment: @ViníciusLima exato. Todo o código que recisa do JSON tem de ser chamado/usado dentro do callback do `getJSON`. Podes por exemplo chamar uma função, passando o JSON como argumento. Assim corres código com esses dados novos vindos do JSON.

Comment: @Sergio Já que não é possível fazer isso, eu fazer assim `<script>var theme = <?= json_encode(new \Skreth\System\Theme()); ?>;</script>` pode ser considerado gambiarra?

Comment: @ViníciusLima funciona bem se os dados forem estáticos. Se precisares de ir buscar dados frescos sem recarregar a página então `getJSON` é o melhor. Não conseguiste implementar com `getJSON`?

Comment: @Sergio são dados estáticos, sobre as cores padrões do tema, tipo: `Secondary: "gray600"` `Featured: "cyan"`. Ai eu gostaria de acessá-las mais ou menos assim: `theme.Secondary`. Dessa forma eu consigo, porém não sei se é 100% correta

Comment: @ViníciusLima ok, então pondo numa `var` parece-me bem