# Javascript PHP retornos

Tags: php, javascript, html

Esse aqui e o HTML

```
<div class="widget widget-table action-table">
  <div class="widget-header"> <i class="icon-check"></i>

  </div>

  <div class="widget-content">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">

      <tbody>
        <br/>
        <center>
          <textarea  cols="150" rows="7" class="input-xxlarge" type="text" id="login" name="login" placeholder="Sua lista"></textarea> <br /><br />

          <button class="btn btn-mini btn btn-success" id="submitValidacao"  type="submit">Iniciar teste</button>
          <button class="btn btn-mini btn btn-danger" type="button">Cancelar e limpar</button>
        </center>

    <hr>
      </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>

<!-- RETORNO -->
<div class="widget widget-table action-table">
  <div class="widget-header"> <i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i>
    <h3>Retorno</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="widget-content">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
     <center>
      <div class="returnEmail"></div>
      <div class="testEmail"></div>
      <div class="resultEmail" style="width:70%; height:100px; overflow:auto; padding:1%; border:1px solid; margin-top:1%;" >Emails Validos<br/></div>
     </center>
     <br>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

no textarea eu coloco uma lista grande de email:nome
ficando assim.

```
email:nome
email2:nome2
email3:nome3
```

assim por diante

e envio o post pro javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.resultEmail').hide();
  $('#submitValidacao').click(function(){
    var logins = $('#logins').val();
    var loginsSplited = logins.split("\n").reverse();
        var loginsSplited = logins.split("\n");

      var loginsSplitedCount = loginsSplited.length;
      $('.returnEmail').html("<hr><b>Testando "+loginsSplitedCount+" Login...<br>Aguarde...</b><br>");
      var counter = 0;

$.each(loginsSplited, function (i, val) {
        $('.testEmail').html("Testando agora = "val);
        $.post('pages/engines/email.php', {
            login: val
        }, function (retorna) {
            $('.resultEmail').show();
        $('.resultEmail').append(retorna);
            counter++;
            if (counter === loginsSplitedCount) {
                $('.returnEmail').html("<hr><b>Testando " + loginsSplitedCount + " Login...<br>Pronto!</b><br>");
                $('.testEmail').html("<font color='gren'>Teste finalizado com sucesso!</font>");
            };
        });
    });

  });
});

</script>
```

agora no  `$('.testEmail').html("Testando agora = "val);` mostra apenas o Testando agora = email:nome que e o primeiro valor da lista que foi adicionada no textarea, e quando finaliza ação ele chama o  `$('.testEmail').html("<font color='gren'>Teste finalizado com sucesso!</font>");`

substituindo o Testando agora = .

o problema e que não consigo passa os valores certinho no Testando agora = , ficando email:nome e quando termina ele já vim o email2:nome2 , pois o php já retorna 1 por 1 ..

Comment: poderia me mostrar o link ?

Comment: Creio que o teu problema aqui é o mesmo que na outra pergunta que marquei como duplicada. Ou seja, tens de ter esse `if (counter === loginsSplitedCount){` dentro de `function(retorna){` porque o ajax é assincrono. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/60852/return-em-each-getjson-jquery

Comment: Isso eu já fiz e não funciono e essa pergunta ai não responde a minha . mesmo assim obrigado

Comment: Acho que não compreendeste a natureza assincrona ainda. Reabri para eu ou otros te explicarem melhor. Mas o problema é de assincronia como na outra pergunta.

Comment: Irei tenta aqui Sergio, irei ler aqui.

Comment: O que quero na verdade e apenas enviar o post e receber as informação que o php retorna :(  se eu carregar uma lista grande ele conta qual ta testando  acho que estou errando em algum lugar .

Comment: Testa isto: http://jsfiddle.net/z1qtj621/

Comment: Do meu ponto de vista o motivo é que por padrao o javascript é assíncrono, o que eu sugiro é alterar para síncrono, assim ele vai executar o `ajax` e so apos terminar que executara o `if` logo abaixo.

Comment: Segue link com resposta sobre síncrono. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821380/how-to-make-a-jquery-post-request-synchronous

Answer (score 3):

O que está a acontecer é que esse ciclo `$.each` está a correr e terminar sozinho. A cada iteração tens `counter++`, ele vai somando e chega ao fim. Depois dele vai ser corrido o que o servidor retorna.

#### Depois?? sim, depois.

O AJAX é assíncrono, e por isso mesmo que ele esteja dentro do seu `$.each` ele vai chamar a função callback com o resultado que o servidor retorna quando o `$.each` já tiver acabado certamente.

#### Como posso controlar o fluxo da aplicação?

Tens de ter como ponto de partida a callback do ajax, pois é aí que o código vai ficar à espera e vai ser chamado quando o servidor responder.

Sugestão:

```
    $.each(loginsSplited, function (i, val) {
        $('.testEmail').html("Testando agora = " + val);
        $.post('pages/engines/email.php', {
            login: val
        }, function (retorna) {
            $('.resultEmail').show();
            $('.resultEmail').append(retorna);
            counter++;
            if (counter === loginsSplitedCount) {
                $('.returnEmail').html("<hr><b>Testando " + loginsSplitedCount + " Login...<br>Pronto!</b><br>");
                $('.testEmail').html("<font color='gren'>Teste finalizado com sucesso!</font>");
            };
        });
    });
```

Comment: @Wender a ver se percebi bem. Como está funciona mas querias que mostrasse um a um apagando o anterior. É isso?

Comment: isso mesmo que preciso

Comment: @Wender mas o AJAX é mto rápido.Você nem vai ver os valores a mudar, vai parecer que ele só mostra o ultimo. Estás consciente disso? Se queres assim muda `+ loginsSplitedCount +` para `+ val +` no código que dei na resposta.

Comment: e não existe a possibilidade de colocar um setInterval ?

Comment: @Wender sim, um `setTimeout` assim: http://jsfiddle.net/jsdyjc9u/

Comment: Testando 97 Login...
Aguarde...
Testando agora = cadastro@satelite.com.br:1961
não muda :/ e no final Testando 97 Login...
Pronto!
Teste finalizado com sucesso! , Muito Obrigado por te me ajudado , mais irei deixa para la , essa função e muito complicado ...

Comment: @Wender sugestão: marca esta pergunta como aceite e coloca outra nova pergunta com o problema que ainda falta. Eu confesso que ainda não percebi o que queres fazer. Senão ajudava a encontrar a solução para esse outro problema.