# Função Javascript retorna Undefined

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Olá !

Tenho uma função Javascript onde uso ajax , preciso que o retorno desta função seja o dado que é retornado pelo ajax. Consigo obter o retorno tranquilo mas não consigo atribuir o valor do retorno a uma variavel para retornar na função.
A função está sempre retornando Undefined, alguém pode me ajudar ???

```
function verifica_cep_cliente(){

            var var_endereco_selecionado = $('#endereco_entrega_utilizar').val();
            var cliente_selecionado = '<?php echo $this->session->cliente_externo_logado ?>';
            var var_forma_entrega = '<?php echo $this->session->FORMAENTREGA_CODIGO ?>';
            var retorno;

            $.ajax({
               url: '<?php echo base_url('Pagamento/verifica_cep_cliente_ajax') ?>',
               type: 'POST',
               dataType: 'TEXT',
               data:"endereco_entrega="+var_endereco_selecionado +"&cliente="+ cliente_selecionado+"&formaentrega="+var_forma_entrega,
               success: function (result){
                   //return result; 
                   retorno = result;
               }
            }); 

           //return retorno;


           alert("retorno " . retorno);


        }
```

Comment: Esse `alert("retorno " . retorno);` ou o código que precisa de `result` tem de estar dentro dessa função `success`. Ela vai correr quando o servidor responder e não há como aceder ao codigo fora dela. Outra duplicada do mesmo problema é: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/63605/129, e há mais

Comment: Hum, ok. O que eu precisava era aceder o valor do ajax para a variavel que esta na função Js.  Mas já resolvi de outra maneira, obrigado pela ajuda.]

Comment: Nesse caso chama a função que precisa da variável de dentro da resposta do ajax. Assim a função é chamada assim que o JavaScript souber a resposta do servidor