# Múltiplos callbacks com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, funções, callback, multiple

Olá, pessoal.
Eu tenho dois callbacks de funções distintas que me fornecem valores que precisam ser utilizados fora destas funções. Segue o código:

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    FB.api('/me/picture?type=normal', function(response) {
        foto = response.data.url;
    });
    nome = response.name;
});

console.log(foto); //Indefinido
console.log(nome); //Indefinido
```

Alguém sabe como posso fazer isso? Obrigado.

Comment: Possivel duplicata: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/60852/129

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O seu código não mostra detalhes completos do que você escreveu depois daquele trecho de código, mas as chamadas a FB.api não são síncronas, logo quando você chama console.log, a comunicação com a API do Facebook ainda está em execução e suas variáveis ainda vazias.

Elas serão preenchidas num momento futuro, devido a chamada assíncrona.

Sua melhor aposta é englobar a chamada a FB.api em uma função e passar um callback. Existem muitas maneiras sofisticadas de se fazer isso, mas um exemplo bem básico, mas funcional, para você entender o contexto:

```
function ObtemNome(callback) {
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        callback(response.name);
    });
}

function ObtemFoto(callback) {
    FB.api('/me/picture?type=normal', function(response) {
        callback(response.data.url);
    });
}

function SalvarNome(nome) {
    console.log(nome);
}

function SalvarFoto(foto) {
    console.log(foto);
}

ObtemNome(SalvarNome);
ObtemFoto(SalvarFoto);
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema pode ser uma coisa simples ou uma coisa complexa, mas no que eu estou vendo parece que você não declarou as variáveis fora da função. Eu sugiro que faça algo assim e veja se continua tendo uma saída ***undefined***:

```
var nome;
var foto;
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    FB.api('/me/picture?type=normal', function(response) {
         foto = response.data.url;
    });
     nome = response.name;
});

console.log(foto); 
console.log(nome);
```

Métodos Internos, geralmente tem saídas internas, mas vc pode fazer uma saída externa chamando um outro método, conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```
var valores = [];
FB.api('/me', function(response) {

    FB.api('/me/picture?type=normal', function(response) {
         valorEntrada(response.data.url, 0);
    });
      valorEntrada(response.name, 1);
});

function valorEntrada(valor, pos) {
   valores[pos] = valor;
}

function valorSaida(pos) {
  return valores[pos];
}

var foto = valorSaida(0);
var nome = valorSaida(1);

console.log(foto); 
console.log(nome);
```

Comment: eu já havia tentado declarar as variáveis antes, esse método não funciona. O segundo método parece válido, mas consegui resolver o problema de uma outra forma.

Obrigado por responder!

Comment: Beleza, aqui tem um bom conteúdo sobre jQuery:
http://www.academia.edu/6245365/Fundamentos_de_jQuery_jQuery_Fundamentals

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver adaptando a solução do AlfredBaudisch. Meu código ficou assim:

```
    function userInfo(callback) {
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            callback(response);
        });
    }

    function userFoto(callback) {
        FB.api('/me/picture?type=normal', function(response) {
            callback(response.data.url);
        });
    }

    userInfo(function(info) {
        userFoto(function(foto) {
            dados = {
                nome: info.name,
                email: info.email,
                facebookId: info.id,
                foto: foto,
            }
            //Faço as operações desejadas com os dados aqui
        });
    });
```

Obrigado, pessoal