# Não conseguindo chamar a mesma variável fora da function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Não estou conseguindo chamar a minha variável `pt1` fora do `function(data)` e dentro da `function getImageItem`.
Sendo que a `function(data)` está dentro da `function getImageItem`.

```
function getImageItem() {
    var item = "";
    jQuery.ajax({

        url: "pegaPortifolio.php/?id=1", //?id="+idUltimo,
        dataType: "json", //Tipo de Retorno
        success: function(data) {
            var pt1 = "";
            var i = 1;
            var ultimo_id = 0;
            var size = 0,
                key;
            for (key in data) {
                if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++; //cod para contar o tamanho do array multidimensional

            } //size , variavel com o tamamho do array

            for (i = 0; i < size; i++) { //monta o html para exibir os dados
                pt1 += '<div class="element-item ' + data[i].menu + '" data-category="transition"><div style="padding:2.5px;"><div style="border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;"><a href="#portfolioModal54" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal"><img src="' + data[i].imageM + '" alt="project 2"><div class="fundo-port"><h1>"' + data[i].tipo + '"</h1><h2>"' + data[i].nome + '"</h2></div></a></div></div></div>';
            }
        }
    });
    //alert(pt1);
    item = pt1; //NÂO PEGA A VARIAVEL
    return item;
}
```

**Parte que quero que a variável seja chamada é na**  `item = pt1; //NÂO PEGA A VARIAVEL`.

Comment: Declare a variável no escopo do método getImageItem

Comment: javascript..
Vou tentar vinicius

Comment: @Vinícius não da certo, ae o pt1 fica como não existente na function(data)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Tens dois problemas aqui:

**#1:** estás a definir a variável dentro de uma função, e por isso ela não é acessível no escopo fora dessa função.

**#2:** o ajax é assíncrono e `return item` vai ser corrido (e a função encerrada) antes de o ajax retornar o seu valor.

#### Acerca de #1:

Repara neste exemplo com o teu problema:

```js
function bar() {
  var foo = 10;
}
bar();
console.log(foo); // dá erro porque "foo" não existe nesse escopo
```

Como podes resolver:

```js
var foo;

function bar() {
  foo = 10;
}
console.log(foo); // undefined
bar();
console.log(foo); // 10
```

#### Acerca de #2:

O segundo problema é que o ajax é assincrono. Isso quer dizer que o código depois deste pedaço `jQuery.ajax()` é corrido **ante** do código que está defenido dentro da [callback](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27182/129), que só vai correr quando houver resposta do servidor. ([exemplo de outra pergunta com o mesmo problema](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/60854/129))

No caso do segundo problema tens de colocar o código que precisa dos dados do ajax, **dentro** dessa [callback](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27182/129), ou chamar uma outra função de dentro do callback, passado a variável nos argumentos.

#### Então como resolvo?

Sugestão:

```
function getImageItem(callback) {
    var item = "";
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "pegaPortifolio.php/?id=1", //?id="+idUltimo,
        dataType: "json", //Tipo de Retorno
        success: function(data) {
            var pt1 = '';
            var ultimo_id = 0,
                size = 0,
                key;
            for (key in data) {
                if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++; //cod para contar o tamanho do array multidimensional
            } //size , variavel com o tamamho do array
            for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) { //monta o html para exibir os dados
                pt1 += '<div class="element-item ' + data[i].menu + '" data-category="transition"><div style="padding:2.5px;"><div style="border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;"><a href="#portfolioModal54" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal"><img src="' + data[i].imageM + '" alt="project 2"><div class="fundo-port"><h1>"' + data[i].tipo + '"</h1><h2>"' + data[i].nome + '"</h2></div></a></div></div></div>';
            }
            callback(pt1); // <- aqui envias de volta para a callback da chamada da função
        }
    });
}
```

E desse modo podes chamar assim:

```
getImageItem(function(dados){
    alert(dados);
});
```

Comment: excelente resposta.

Answer (score 1):

O que acontece, @kaiquemix, é que a execução do ajax por padrão é assincrona, ou seja, ele vai executar o `alert(pt1)` antes da requisição ajax terminar.

Uma possível solução seria:

```
function getImageItem() {
    var item = "";
    jQuery.ajax({

        url: "pegaPortifolio.php/?id=1", //?id="+idUltimo,
        dataType: "json", //Tipo de Retorno
        async : false,
        success: function(data) {

            var i = 1;
            var ultimo_id = 0;
            var size = 0,
                key;
            for (key in data) {
                if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++; //cod para contar o tamanho do array multidimensional

            } //size , variavel com o tamamho do array

            for (i = 0; i < size; i++) { //monta o html para exibir os dados
                item += '<div class="element-item ' + data[i].menu + '" data-category="transition"><div style="padding:2.5px;"><div style="border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;"><a href="#portfolioModal54" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal"><img src="' + data[i].imageM + '" alt="project 2"><div class="fundo-port"><h1>"' + data[i].tipo + '"</h1><h2>"' + data[i].nome + '"</h2></div></a></div></div></div>';
            }
        }
    });

    return item;
}
```

Note que a variável `item` continua sendo criada antes da execução ajax, porém, dentro da `function` `success`, ao invés de atribuir valor à variável `pt1`, atribuo diretamente à variável `item`.

Também foi incluído o parâmetro 'async:false', tornando essa requisição ajax `sincrona`, ou seja, todo o código que está após a requisição ajax só será executado após o término da requisição.

Comment: `async : false,` é uma péssima ideia. Não dou `-1` porque algures no tempo o jQuery criou essa opção mas as versões modernas do jQuery já não têm isso.

Comment: Olá thiago... bom isso deu certo na parte de copiar, porem ele quebra o plugim do isotope para trocar com os menus e só repeti o ulimo bloco do banco de dados mas quero que apareça os outros que não estão aparecendo sem aperta carrega mais.