# dom so atualiza no fim do evento

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, front-end, eventos

Ola,

tenho um botao com um evento click, e quando clico nele, realizo uma requisição ajax em um foreach.
gostaria de abrir um modal de loading para rodar enquanto as requisiçoes estao sendo feitas, mas o modal so abre quando todas terminam e o evento acaba.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $('#loading').modal();

                var contadorEnviados = 0;
                var contadorErros = 0;

                $('#botao').click(function(event){
                     event.preventDefault();
                     $('#loading').modal('open');
                     var emails = $('#emails').val().split("\n");

                     emails.forEach(function(email){
                          if(fazRequisicao(email)){
                               contadorEnviados++;
                          }
                          else{
                               contadorErros++;
                          }
                          atualizaContadores(contadorEnviados,contadorErros);
                     });

                     inicializaContador();
                     $('#loading').modal('close');
                });

           });
```

função fazRequisicao

```
function fazRequisicao(email){
  $.get("teste.php", {email: email}, function(resposta){
      return resposta;
 });
```

}

Comment: Esse loop é síncrono? como sabes quando `fazRequisicao` acabou?

Comment: sou meio iniciante, entao desculpa a ignorancia.
O que seria um loop síncrono?
e sei que ele acabou quando retorna o valor la na funçao

Comment: E se você no lugar de usar #loading.modal('open') usar style display:block, muda o resultado?

Comment: Nao paulo, ele só e aplicado quando o bloco do evento chega ao fim

Comment: Podes mostrar o código dessa função fazRequisicao?

Comment: Acabei de editar o post, sergio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essa função `fazRequisicao` não dá retorno síncrono. O `return resposta;` não tem nenhum efeito para o `if(fazRequisicao(email)){`. Ou seja o `forEach` corre até ao fim antes de sequer a primeira `fazRequisicao` responder (podes ler mais [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/107225/129). Tens de mudar a lógica.

Podes fazer isso com Promisses, e assim tens a certeza que todas as funcões foram chamadas e respondidas.

Muda a tua função para:

```js
function fazRequisicao(email) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    $.get("teste.php", {email: email})
      .done(resolve)
      .fail(reject);
      .always(function(xhr, status, deferred) {
        if (deferred.isResolved()) contadorEnviados++;
        else contadorErros++;
        atualizaContadores(contadorEnviados, contadorErros);
      });
  });
});
}
```

e depois podes usar o Promise.all que espera por todas as requesições:

```js
$('#botao').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#loading').modal('open');
  inicializaContador();
  var emails = $('#emails').val().split("\n");
  Promise.all(emails.map(fazRequisicao)).then(function(respostas) {
    $('#loading').modal('close');
  ));
});
```