# Lidando com resultados de requisições síncronas e assíncronas

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, assincronismo

Possuo uma função que dispara uma requisição ajax para uma rota, veja:

```
var getInstituicoesSemUsuario = function(tipo)
{
    var resultado = "";

    $.ajax(
    {                       
        url: "{{path_for('instituicao.sem.responsavel')}}",
        data: "tu=" + tipo,
        type: "GET",
        async: false,                       
        success: function(resposta)
        {
            resultado = resposta;
        }
    });

    return resultado;
}
```

Com a opção `async` definida para `false` é possível obter o retorno da função `getInstituicoesSemUsuario()`, porém, o Google Chrome emite o seguinte aviso:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.

Em poucas palavras, uma chamada síncrona parece afetar a experiencia do usuário final.

No entanto, se eu remover a opção `async` ou defini-la para `true` o aviso some, mas, eu não consigo pegar o resultado da requisição.

## Dúvidas

1. Como eu posso obter o resultado de uma requisição ajax assíncrona?
2. Por que uma requisição síncrona afeta a experiencia do usuário?
3. Há cenários no qual eu possa utilizar requisições síncronas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Respostas:

1. Como eu posso obter o resultado de uma requisição ajax assíncrona?

Tens de usar [callbacks](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27177/o-que-%C3%A9-callback/27182?s=1%7C0.0000#27182), [promises](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16921/129) ou [async/await](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/211505/como-eu-posso-utilizar-o-async-await-do-javascript/211572?s=3%7C0.0000#211572). Podes ler mais aqui [sobre alternativas de encadeamento de funções assíncronas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/140814/alternativas-de-encadeamento-de-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-ass%C3%ADncronas/140883?s=2%7C0.0000#140883).

2. Por que uma requisição síncrona afeta a experiencia do usuário?

Imagina que o servidor que estás a contactar demora a responder,  ou não responde de todo... aí o browser fica bloqueado à espera eternamente e tens de recarregar a página ou fechar o browser para poder usa-lo de novo. No caso de um carrinho de compras por exemplo isso pode ser muito mau para o utilizador que perde o que estava gravado.

3. Há cenários no qual eu possa utilizar requisições síncronas?

Não. Hoje em dia isso está obsoleto == proibido.

---

Sobre o problema concreto na pergunta, é [parecido com este outro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/107225/129), e podes resolver como as alternativas que indiquei em `1.`. Um exemplo com `deferred` (a promise do jQuery) poderia ser assim:

```js
var getInstituicoesSemUsuario = function(tipo) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: "{{path_for('instituicao.sem.responsavel')}}",
    data: "tu=" + tipo,
    type: "GET"
  });
}

// e depois quando precisares:
getInstituicoesSemUsuario('foo').done(function(resultado) {
  console.log(resultado);
});
```

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss obrigado! Estava a _inglezar_ demais :) Por curiosidade fui à procura e [encontrei isto](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/140/12).