# Não estou conseguindo ler esse JSON

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Esse é um arquivo .json que eu criei só para entender

```
{
    "campo":
        [
            {"nome":"Lucas vidotti"}

        ]
}
```

Eu sei que para ler esse valor com o jquery eu preciso fazer 
`$.getJSON` e manipular pela key, mas eu não estou conseguindo ler o json e joga no html

Comment: Pela estrutura, seria algo assim: `let val = $.getJSON; val.campo[0].nome;`

Comment: Não sei como recebe o json, mas se está nesse estrutura, é essa a sintaxe para a leitura.

`.` para acessar key de objeto e `[indice]` para acessar item do array.

Comment: Você precisa passar o arquivo `.json` para a leitura ser efetuada

Comment: Eu assisti uns tutoriais e tentei fazer assim 
$(function(){
   
   $("#mos").click(function(){
        $.getJSON("main.json",function(){
           $("#span").html(campo.nome);
           // então aqui dentro eu preciso colocar o campo[0].nome? 
           
        });
       });
   });

Comment: @lucas depende de como está trabalhando, com callback, síncrono, etc

Comment: se uma resposta lhe servir marque-a como aceita, veja como em https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx7Ts.png e porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079. Aproveita e faça um tour em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 2):

Por partes, conceitos a ter em conta:

- `$.getJSON` é [assíncrono](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/107225/129), não podes fazer somente `var x = $.getJSON;`
- a API é `$.getJSON(<endereço>, callback);`, ou seja essa função consome o endereço e depois executa a [callback](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27177/o-que-%C3%A9-callback/27182#27182) quando a resposta retornar
- a [callback](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27177/o-que-%C3%A9-callback/27182#27182) recebe como argumento da função o resultado, ou seja o JSON

Assim o que procuras é :

```
$("#mos").click(function(){
  $.getJSON("main.json",function(json){
    const campo = json.campo;
    const nome = campo[0].nome;
    console.log(nome); // deve dar "Lucas vidotti"
  });
});
```

Comment: muito obrigado me ajudou bastante !

Comment: Oi @lucas! A minha intenção é resolver o problema completamente e não "somente ajudar" :) Ainda tens perguntas ou partes que não compreendes relacionadas com este post? Conseguiste pôr isso a funcionar?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var json = {
    "campo":
        [
            {"nome":"Lucas vidotti"}

        ]
}

$("#mos").click(function(){
    let quem = json.campo[0].nome;
    $( "#resultado" ).html( quem );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="mos">mostra</button>

<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado me ajudou bastante !!!