# Requisições AJAX e WeakMaps

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ecmascript-5

Enquanto eu colocava em prática o que eu eu aprendi até agora sobre a ES2015 com a Babel. especificamente sobre WeakMaps, cheguei num problema que eu não sei porque acontece e, com isso, não sei como resolver.

Eu tenho um WeakMap definido pra armazenar informações vindas de uma Requisição AJAX a qual só é disparada se esse WeakMap não tiver nada armazenado.

Eu cheguei a isso:

```
class User {

    constructor( id ) {

        id = Number( id );

        if( id <= 0 || isNaN( id ) ) {
            throw new TypeError( 'Invalid User ID' );
        }

        _id.set( this, id );
    }

    getID() {
        return _id.get( this );
    }

    getData() {

        let _this = this;

        if( _data.get( _this ) === undefined ) {

            _this.loadData().done( function( data ) {

                // JSON is indeed successfully loaded

                console.log( data );

                _data.set( _this, data );

                // WeakMap is indeed set correctly

                console.log( _data.get( _this ) );
            });
        }

        // But here it's undefined again!

        console.log( _data.get( _this ) );

        return _data.get( _this );
    }

    loadData() {

        return $.get({
            url: '/users/' + _id.get( this, data ),
        });
    }
}

let _id   = new WeakMap;
let _data = new WeakMap;

// ---------------

var user = new User( 1 );

console.log( user.getID(), user.getData() ); // 1 undefined
```

Até onde eu sei o WeakMap foi definido corretamente, tanto é que o mesmo é feito com o ID do usuário e este pode ser obtido normalmente, descartando, assim, possíveis problemas com o *transcompiler*.

Mas as informações vindas por AJAX, mesmo que estejam vindo corretamente dentro do jquery.done() não podem ser acessadas fora dele.

A única forma que consegui fazer funcionar foi setando `async: false` no `$.ajax`, o que eu sei que não é certo.

O que estou fazendo de errado? Sem saber o porquê eu não posso nem pesquisar sobre o assunto e tentar por mim mesmo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu não entendo de JavaScript ao ponto de dizer que esta é a solução correta mas eu pesquisei MUITO e li inúmeras respostas tanto no stack Overflow<sup>en</sup> como Internet à fora, as quais na tentativa de ensinar as pessoas a pescarem, acabaram matando elas de fome com respostas quase intermináveis, complexas ou que simplesmente acabavam escondendo a solução em meio à tantas informações nem tão necessárias assim.

A quem de interesse for:

```
class User {

    constructor( id ) {

        id = Number( id );

        if( id <= 0 || isNaN( id ) ) {
            throw new TypeError( 'Invalid User ID' );
        }

        _id.set( this, id );
    }

    getID() {
        return _id.get( this );
    }

    getData() {

        if( _data.get( this ) === undefined ) {
            _data.set( this, this.loadData() );
        }

        return _data.get( this );
    }

    loadData() {
        return $.getJSON( CARD_LIST + '/player/' + _id.get( this ) );
    }
}

let _data = new WeakMap;

// ---------------

var user = new User( 1 );

user.getData().done( function( data ) {

    console.log( data );
})
```

Não é o que eu tinha em mente inicialmente, já que vou ter que usar jQuery.done() cada vez que for utilizar um simples *getter* (que na minha opinião deveria trazer as informações prontas pra uso) tampouco poderia explicar os "comos" ou os 'porquês".

Seria bom saber, claro, e se alguém quiser/puder responder explicando de forma didática seria incrível, mas por agora eu humildemente espero que ajude alguém mais que esteja tentando extrair informações simples de respostas/comentários pouco amigáveis pra quem não entende bem do assunto como eu.

Answer (score 0):

A questão aqui é basicamente a mesma que [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/60854/129), ou [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/107225/129). Ou seja: o ajax é assíncrono. Isso quer dizer que:

```
// pseudo código:
var x = 10;
ajax(function(){
    x = 20;
});
console.log(x); // dá 10
```

O que acontece é que o ajax demora tempo a executar e, mesmo sendo muito rápido) o código vai continuar a correr chegando ao `console.log` **antes** do ajax ser completado.

A solução para isso é chamar o `console.log` quando o `ajax` tiver algo para retornar. Isso pode ser feito com [callback](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27182/129), ou com [Promises](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16921/129).

A solução é, [como encontraste](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/180042/129), fazer `getData` retornar um objeto deferido, tipo Promise:

```
user.getData().done(function(data){
    console.log( data );
})
```